# Using MsgPack custom serializer in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, msgpack, messagepack

I am experiencing difficulties with using MsgPack custom serializer in C#. Say, I have the following class:

```
public class A
{
    public int intA;
    public string strA;
    public B nestedB;
}
public class B
{
    public string strB;
    public int intB; 
}
```

I am writing custom deserializer for class A. So my method looks like:

```
protected override A UnpackFromCore(Unpacker unpacker)
{
     int inta;
     unpacker.ReadInt32(out inta);
     string stra;
     unpacker.ReadString(out stra);
     B b = new B;
     // ??? How to get B from unpacker
     unpacker.?????(b);
}
```

Everything goes fine with primitive types, but how to extract instance of class B from unpacker? Wiki documentation is quite poor, and not to much information on the Internet regarding MessagePack C# implementation.
Any kind of help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found so far:

- Before serializing an instance, MsgPack serializes the number of instance fields;
- After that all fields are serialized alphabetically by default, if they are not marked with DataMember or MessagePackMember attributes (otherwise they are ordered by order or id attribute properties respectively);
- Unfortunately I haven't found anything what could help to determine this piece of data which holds the number of fields, since all attributes like IsCollectionHeader, IsArrayHeader, IsMapHeader on it are set to false;

So this is still unclear.

Actually it's not necessary for me to dig deeper in this, so I consider this problem as resolved. Maybe my answer could be helpful for somebody else.